# scrapy, loop over list of divs

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using scrapy and would like to get all tags (with text) stored in a list and go through this list to get what I want div by div.

Below my code, I stored all tags that I want in divs, this is ok, but the loop after is not working. error : ('str' object has no attribute 'css')

```
def parse_0(self, response):
    divs = response.css('div.resultList.mB15.hiddenOverflow.listing').extract()

    for div in divs:
        yield {
            'prix': str(div.css('div.fieldPrice ::text').extract_first()).replace("\\xa0", "").replace("\u20ac", ""),
            'lien': div.xpath('.//a/@href').extract_first(),
            'date_scrap': time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"),
        }
```

here the image which represents the embedded div:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlsIq.png)
thanks

Comment: If I use this (which is solution without extract) : for div in response.css('div.resultList.mB15.hiddenOverflow.listing'): blabla.... the loop is stopped after first iteration.

Comment: Are you sure that there's more than 1 div? It would be easier for us to help if you attach a url of the page you're scraping.

Comment: @ stasdeep I added image which showing the embedded div, for me I need to get each price and link stored in each div adLineContainer

Comment: I see you are checking HTML that is rendered in browser, but raw response may look different.

Answer (score 1):

Dont' call `extract()` on the selector. `extract()` returns a str.

Answer (score 0):

`divs = response.css('div.resultList.mB15.hiddenOverflow.listing').extract()`
here when you use extract it will return you list of selector converted into string.
if you wanna keep using `extract()` then convert the `div` into `selector`
otherwise you can skip extract() and the code should run fine.

Thanks.